# List of words and letters to list of letters

Tags: python, list

I have a list which has strings of length `1` up to `n`:

```
a = ['a','aq','thw','z']
```

I'm trying to obtain a flat list with only length `1` elements, expanding those the length of which is greater than `1`. My current solution is:

```
l = []
for i in a:
    l = l + list(i)
print(l)
['a', 'a', 'q', 't', 'h', 'w', 'z']
```

Is there a more straight forward way of doing this avoiding a `for` loop?

My impression is that there might not be, however I'm curious where as to know if there is some other more efficient perhaps built-in method to accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because Python iterates over all iterables the same way, all of the answers from [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) should also work for you.

Comment: Reopening for now. If anyone finds a better duplicate (there's likely to be one, I'm surprised this hasn't been asked before) then please ping me and I'll close again.

Comment: I did give this a good search before asking. The fact that answers from other questions are valid to solve the problem does not make it a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the easiest way I can think to do it, with `str.join` + listification.

```
>>> list(''.join(a))
['a', 'a', 'q', 't', 'h', 'w', 'z']
```

There's also the solution with `chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(a)) # Thanks, @Patrick Haugh!
['a', 'a', 'q', 't', 'h', 'w', 'z']
```

---

They're all pretty fast.

```
a2 = a * 100000
%timeit list(''.join(a2))
%timeit list(chain.from_iterable(a2))
%timeit [letter for word in a2 for letter in word]

11.1 ms ± 247 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
32.3 ms ± 863 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
50.2 ms ± 1.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: The `chain` solution should just be `list(chain.from_iterable(a))`

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [letter for word in a for letter in word]
['a', 'a', 'q', 't', 'h', 'w', 'z']
```